# Applying a custom style to all my buttons on a page

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have a page.

When a button is pressed i want it to go to 50% transparency.

I used to have the default blue background of the button show up when pressed and I have removed that by using a VisualState in my page (by removing the default styles for button press).

I now want to apply the transparency style.

I modified my markup to this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="50"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

and this is one of my button:

```
<Button Name="btnDel" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <Button.Background>  
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Images/del.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

and the error I get is:

**Animation target not specified.**

Comment: Your `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` lacks `Storyboard.TargetName` - you change *Opacity* but you haven't specified which element's.

Comment: Hi Romasz, thanks for taking pity on me :). This is all new stuff to me and being slightly autistic I find reading MSDN help files not ideal.  If I want to affect all the images on my page I would assume that I do not specify an element name?  Obviously, I am wrong but I just do not know how to accomplish what I want.  Is Opacity a fair enough property to use?  There is no intellisense so I do not know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `DoubleAnimation` to animate the `Grid`'s `Opacity`, like this -

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. Where would i put that line of markup please?  thanks

Comment: HI, yes, that is where I put it. But does not work. The button when pressed is unaffected?